# How to hide all children of a container except a specific one using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="container">
<div id="specific_one">..</div>
...
</div>
```

I want to hide all children of `#container` except `#specific_one`, how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried something like:

```
$('#container *:not(#specific_one)').hide();
```

or

```
$('#container').children(':not(#specific_one)').hide();
```

and I think this one is faster...

```
$('#container #specific_one').siblings().hide(); //please comment on this guys...
```

Comment: functional 'selecting' is always faster than doing it just with selectors. Functions like .not() just do an array slice, whereas ':not()' needs to traverse the DOM.

Comment: (What's more, the non-standard jQuery selectors like `:not` mean the whole selector can't be handed off to the fast native selector engine in modern browsers with Selectors-API support. Doing negation in a separate filtering step with the `not()` method is typically faster.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#container').children().not('#specific_one').hide();
```